# downloading files from s3 bucket in amazon ec2 to local drive in windows 7

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I am trying to download all  sample files from my s3 bucket in amazon ec2 via boto3 and python3 script to my local hard drive.
Here is the script.

```
#downloading files from s3
import boto3
import sys
import os
import argparse
import threading
from botocore.client import Config
instance_id = "i-03e7f6391a0f523ee"
action = 'ON'
ec2 = boto3.client('ec2')
s3=boto3.resource('s3')
for bucket in s3.buckets.all():
    print(bucket.name)
my_bucket=s3.Bucket('tkbucket32')
print("listing all files in bucket")
for s3_file in my_bucket.objects.all():
    print(s3_file.key)

s3.meta.client.download_file('tkbucket32', 'hello.txt', '/tmp/hello.txt')
```

Currently there are following files in bucket

> hello.txt myhomepage.html

Now I want them to be downloaded to

```
D:\folder1\folder2\folder3
```

I am running scripts in Windows 7.
My problem is this line

```
s3.meta.client.download_file('tkbucket32', 'hello.txt', '/tmp/hello.txt')
```

Where do I specify the path of on local hard drive where I want to download these files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this line:

```
s3.meta.client.download_file('tkbucket32', 'hello.txt', '/tmp/hello.txt')
```

to:

```
s3.meta.client.download_file('tkbucket32', 'hello.txt', 'D:\\folder1\\folder2\\folder3\\hello.txt')
```

Comment: I tried to do it this way `file_path="D:\\folder1\\folder2\\folder3\\"
s3.meta.client.download_file('tkbucket32', 'hello.txt', file_path+'hello.txt')` I get EOL while scanning string literal.
The method which you suggested I tried that also, I get error 
`return open(filename, mode)
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'D:\\folder1\\folder2\\folder3\\hello.txt.8AEd213A'``

Comment: I have updated the question with error and code and more details based on what you suggested.

Comment: You need to escape backslashes. Look again at my answer. Notice the "\\" between directory names. Also, don't change the details on your question. Otherwise the answers that you receive won't make sense to your modified question.